# How to pass variables to html5 using google swiffy converting swf

Tags: asp.net, html, flash, google-swiffy

I am using swiffy to convert old swf files(e-greeting card) to html5 in asp.net. I was able to convert it but the problem is the swf needs to be passed with variables {to}, {from}, {message}.

I googled and tried the code below but with no luck, the html5 version text animation does not get replaced with the set values.

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {});
stage.setFlashVars("{to}=Test User");    
stage.start();
```

the website  is old and using a third party to load the flash and the code is below

```
Turbine.Turbine7 turbine = new Turbine.Turbine7();
turbine.Variable["{to}"] = to;
turbine.Variable["{from}"] = from;
turbine.Variable["{sMsg}"]= msg;
turbine.load(swfurl);
turbine.GenerateHTMLFirst();
```

Unfortunately i don't have the source code for the swf. I tried to use a decompiler i saw a definetext object with the details below

```
[
xmin -6
ymin 114
xmax 1221
ymax 499
][
font 106
height 360
color #ffff00
y 400
]{sMsg}
```

Need your help please.... Thank you.
Nai

Answer (score 1):

Just to share the solution to my problem...

Apparently, the problem is the object in flash is static and therefore swiffy is converting it as an image and not as text. What I did is, decompile the .swf to .fla file. After converting I open the file in flash professional then update the text object to dynamic. Then I had swiffy convert the new swf file again.

In my implementation, I just need to find the pattern(e.g. {Name}) and update it in asp.net code.